# Doing a custom menu in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, menubar

I need to finish a software to present at university as my career final work. The deadline is pretty close, and I wanted to do a pretty main menu window. I´m working with winforms with some WPF usercontrols(buttons and all that tiny things). Now, as winform cant be costumizable like WPF, I was thinking of making the main window in WPF. But I have a big problem, I know too little of WPF and XAML.

I use Expression blend, but it´s difficult to do what I need there too.

What I wanted to do is something this:

![enter image description here][1]

I need a menu in the top, but it has to have an image with a tittle below. Then, when the mouse enters there, it will open and show the menu items.

To try to achieve this, I did this:

- Created a UserControl with a rectangle where the image and text will be, and a menu below with some menu items. I also used storyboard for animation.

![enter image description here][2]

Anyways, I think I´m doing all wrong. I think there might be a way to do this more easily. For example, I had to create events like: when the mouse enters the rectangle, the menu is visible, if not, its hidden. Also, I have to create a storyboard for each menuitem. I mean, to change the backcolor when it´s selected and all that.

I really need help here. Please if somebody can help me coding at least the menu structure it will be awesome.

**QUESTION CLOSED** I finally managed to do it with Windows Forms

Comment: "..don't have the time to learn." With all due respect that isn't going to win you many popularity points on SO. Perhaps you should've started this project sooner.

Comment: You're not going to find anyone on SO willing to just give you the code, especially if you won't take the time to attempt to learn things on your own.

Comment: Maybe focus on something you do know rather than waiting until the last minute to use a technology you don't know?

Comment: @KodeKreachor I started the project soon enough to finish it. I just didnt know of the existence of WPF until some months ago. I think you guys misunderstood me, its not that I want you to code me the entire menu, I need help to deal with the structure. I need some guide here, I showed what I have done so far because I want to know if I´m in the right track or if I´m doing it all wrong. Besides, I´m not asking to get help for an entire app. I just dealing with some crappy custom menu. But thanks dudes, you are really helpful.

Comment: Oh I´m sorry, "Please if somebody can help me with coding" didnt mean to somebody give me the code. It meant to help ME coding the menu.

Answer (score 3):

This link shows you how to make a context menu for a button. You will have to edit the XAML and code-behind by hand, probably, but this will get you started:

http://dotnetlearning.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/dropdown-menu-in-wpf/

Copied from the site:

Here the code:

```
<Button Content="Click Me"  
    Click="Button_Click" 
    ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False"  
    Margin="42,40,89,72">  
    <Button.ContextMenu>  
        <ContextMenu >  
            <MenuItem Header="Menu 1"/>  
            <MenuItem Header="Menu 1"/>  
            <MenuItem Header="Menu 1"/>  
            <MenuItem Header="Menu 1"/>  
        </ContextMenu>  
    </Button.ContextMenu>  
</Button>
```

The second step consist in displaying the ContextMenu when the button is clicked. This is achieved by few lines of code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{  
    (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;  
    (sender as Button).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (sender as Button);  
    (sender as Button).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;  
    (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;  
}
```

If you want to look at other articles to help, the google search tearm I used was `how to make pull down menu in wpf` Good luck!